# Avoid primary key constraint violation in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, primary-key

I have an application where insertion is a part of a transaction. Now the value to be inserted comes from the user, so it may violate the primary key constraint of uniqueness. But I do not wish to abort the full transaction if an exception is raised, I want to ignore and move on to complete the rest of the inserts in the transaction. I am new to Postgres, I was wondering if triggers can be the way to implement this feature. If not triggers then what? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `insert ... on conflict do nothing`

Comment: If the value of the PK comes from the user, then it's a "natural key". Avoid natural keys, unless there are compelling reasons to use them. They are generally a bad idea.

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name on conflict works

Comment: @TheImpaler It's not natural key, just that the user may not know that that particular value already exists and may try to add that record which must be overridden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `on conflict` in your upsert operations :

```
insert into table ([list of columns])
values ([list of values])
on conflict (id) DO NOTHING ;
```

I assumed id is your primary key